# Switch or else if statements - what is more clear in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

As in title. There are a lot similar questions but I will give different example: I have 2 enums

```
enum A
{
  A_ONE,
  A_TWO
};

enum B
{
  B_ONE,
  B_TWO
};
```

What is more clear switch by enum A and then in all cases switch by enum B?

```
A type1;
B type2;

switch(type1)
{
case A_ONE:
    switch(type2)
    {
    case B_ONE:
       //statement1
       break;
    case B_TWO:
       //statement2
       break;
     }
     break;
case A_TWO:
     switch(type2)
    {
    case B_ONE:
       //statement3
       break;
    case B_TWO:
       //statement4
       break;
     }
     break;
}
```

or using else if

```
if(type1 == A_ONE && type2 == B_ONE)
    //statement1
else if(type1 == A_ONE && type2 == B_TWO)
    //statement2
else if(type1 == A_TWO && type2 == B_ONE)
    //statement3
else if(type1 == A_TWO && type2 == B_TWO)
    //statement4
```

Which is better practice? What do you preffer

Comment: Their uses are not synonymous. Switch statements are used in cases where discrete values are known and compared against; If statements do that, but also allow for checking against any boolean expression. There are things you cannot do with a switch statement that you can do with and if statement.

Comment: Side note: you should name the enum values ONE and TWO in both cases. They are already qualified by A and B. You don't need to repeat that in the name.

Comment: Is there other alternatives ? As merging `enum A` and `B` which seems related, splitting in sub-functions (so the 2 `switch (type2)` doesn't appear in the `switch(type1)`...

Comment: I cant merge it. It is only example but in my code this two enums arent related.

Comment: They have a kind of relation (according to *statement[1-4]*), but I agree that merging them may not have sense in your case. Polymorphism on *statement* might also be an option.

Comment: @EJP: I disagree. Not only stylistically, but because unless you put the enums themselves in distinct scopes, [what you suggest is impossible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60fbd33a1cdac11c). Remember, they will be named `A_ONE` etc, not `A::A_ONE` etc. That's important.

Answer (score 2):

It's more of a style issue than anything else. If you are only checking for the presence of two conditions over limited sets of data, the `switch()` approach is easier to follow, and less prone to issues (forgetting the final `else` to go with `if`, `else if`; using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equivalence operator `==`; accidentally using the binary bitwise AND `&` operator instead of the binary logical AND `&&` operator, etc).

The only potential downside of the `switch()` approach is to forget to put a `break` statement under each case, but you can use [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) or [enable `-Wswitch-fallthrough`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7652) to cause compiler warnings or failures in such an event.

## Edit

---

Forgot to mention to always have a `default` case in switches. I always assume it's a given.

So, use:

- `-Wswitch-default`: force default cases in switch statements.
- I stand corrected, `-Wswitch-fallthrough` is not yet implemented. Too bad, since clang has had it for a while. Use CppCheck as part of your build/QA process to avoid getting bit by this oversight.

Comment: I just checked at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html and cannot find `-Wswitch-fallthrough` option. May be it should be `-Wswitch`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. 
I think it is a matter of taste, personal preferences or company standards.

In the case of two enumeration literals *if-else* statement may be equivalent to the *switch* statement. But as the number of literals grows the *if-else* statements may become unmaintainable or difficult to read, while the *switch* statement may help to systematically cover all cases.

Additionally I would suggest to consider putting `default` case to cover abnormal circumstances.

Comment: _"I would suggest to always put default case to cover abnormal circumstances"_ Sometimes, but at other times, if you know that the input doesn't come from users and will always be a valid enum member, if you omit the `default` case then you'll get a compiler warning if you ever add to the enum but forget to add to the switch. As with everything, apply thought and reason, rather than following blanket rules.

Comment: Yes, I understand. So I changed my response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this:

- Use 'else-if' statements if the amount of data you´re evaluating is low.
- Use 'switch' when there is a considerable amount of data to test.

In your example there are only 4 posibble combinations, so it´s ok to do it that way, but think for example: what if your enum A would have 10 elements and enum B would have 6, yo would need 60 'else-if' statements to cover all posibilities, which later when you try to read it may become difficult, instead if you would use 'switch' you also need 60 declarations, but later you will find it more easy for read or modification